# Why multiple Solver Loops take too much time to finish?

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have been trying to use the Excel Solver to max out my revenue problem. The problem is this solver only allows me to run with limited variable number. My case is in hourly time series for `1 year` meaning `8760` rows with multiple columns. The good news is it allows me to run for `1 day (24 rows)` when I define all my constraints and set for variables. Therefore, I have thought that coding for 1 day's solver and looping it for every day through 8760s row as I have given below. But the problem is it takes too much time to finish. Those constraints are also including some formulation like revenue-cost etc. I need if are there any opportunities to make this progress fast enough? It takes 4-5 hours now.

Actually, I have summarized what I have done but in addition to those, I have also searched for how can I handle this with Python to make it easier and faster but could not find...

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim a As Integer
a = 24
Dim b As Long
For b = 0 To 364
Dim i As Integer
i = 16 + (a * b)
Dim j As Integer
j = i + 23
Dim k As Integer
k = i - 1
Dim l As Integer
l = j - 1

    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$V$13", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$H$" & i & ":" & "$J$" & j _
        , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$" & i & ":" & "$H$" & j, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$G$" & i & ":" & "$G$" & j
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$" & i & ":" & "$I$" & j, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$D$" & i & ":" & "$D$" & j
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$" & i & ":" & "$I$" & j, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$L$" & i & ":" & "$L$" & j, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$F$3"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$" & i & ":" & "$J$" & j, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$F$3"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$" & i & ":" & "$J$" & j, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$M$" & i & ":" & "$M$" & j
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$" & i & ":" & "$J$" & j, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$" & i & ":" & "$N$" & j, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$F$6"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$" & i & ":" & "$N$" & j, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$F$12"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$O$" & i & ":" & "$O$" & j, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$V$13", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$$H$" & i & ":" & "$J$" & j _
        , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve True
        Next b

End Sub
```

The results are coming out but the time is the problem...

Comment: VB is single threaded so its only doing one at a time

Comment: High-performance NLP (Nonlinear Programming) solvers are readily available. Some examples: SNOPT, MINOS, CONOPT, KNITRO, IPOPT. You can try out a few on [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/).